# How to add a 'Link to current location' in a google custom map?

Tags: google-maps

I'm making a custom google map for a game, everything is going very well, but i'm having dificulties adding an option for people to link to a current part on the map.

for example: http://www.gta4.net/map/?lat=-19.775390625&lng=-7.91015625&z=5

does this function exists in the api or is this a custom made script ?
If so, how could i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality doesn't exist in the API, but is easy to add (not tested):

```
 // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
 // looking something like  "?marker=3"

 // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
 var query = location.search.substring(1);

 // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
 var pairs = query.split("&");
 for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
   // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
   var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
   var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
   var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();

   // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
   if (argname == "id") {id = unescape(value);}
   if (argname == "marker") {index = parseFloat(value);}
   if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
   if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
   if (argname == "zoom") {zoom = parseInt(value);}
   if (argname == "type") {
     // from the v3 documentation 8/24/2010
     // HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images. 
     // ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map. 
     // SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images. 
     // TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation. 
     if (value == "m") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
     if (value == "k") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
     if (value == "h") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;}
     if (value == "t") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;}

   }
 }

// create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
    mapTypeId: maptype,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: maptype
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomap.html?id=Marker%20One&lat=43.784976&lng=-81.018677&zoom=7&type=m) (ported from the example on [this page of Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/linktothis.htm))